# middle align divs containing glyphicons and breadcrumb

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap row containing 4 divs that hide/push/pull with changing screen size. HTML and CSS code below:

```
<div class="row" id="dtRow">
    <div class="hidden-md hidden-lg col-xs-1 dtRowCols" id="dtCol0">
        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" id="chCity"></div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-11 col-md-4 col-md-push-4 dtRowCols" id="dtCol1">
            <ul class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a></a></li>
                <li><a></a></li>
                <li><a></a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4 col-md-push-4 dtRowCols text-right" id="dtCol2">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Change City" value="">
    </div> 
    <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4 col-md-pull-8 dtRowCols" id="dtCol3">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 dtCol3Gc">loc</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 dtCol3Gc">date</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end dTRow -->
```

CSS:

```
#dtRow {
 border: 1px solid red;
display: flex;   
}

.dtRowCols {
border: 2px dotted blue;    
background-color: rgba(128,128,128,.4);     
}

#chCity {
margin: auto;  
}
```

However, the glyphicon and the breadcrum won't align vertically/horizontally in the middle. Please help. Screen shot attached. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdSIc.png)

Comment: would you maybe create a jsfiddle for us to see all the code that is causing your issue?

Answer (score 0):

you should use *`position`* and *`transform`* to align both horizontal and vertical your glyphicon and for your breadcrumb you should change its default *`margin`* as:

### Code Snippet

```css
#dtRow {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
}
.dtRowCols {
  border: 2px dotted blue;
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, .4);
}
/* Change in your CSS */

.breadcrumb {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
#chCity {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row" id="dtRow">
  <div class="hidden-md hidden-lg col-xs-1 dtRowCols" id="dtCol0">
    <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" id="chCity"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-11 col-md-4 col-md-push-4 dtRowCols" id="dtCol1">
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
      <li>
        <a></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4 col-md-push-4 dtRowCols text-right" id="dtCol2">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Change City" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4 col-md-pull-8 dtRowCols" id="dtCol3">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-6 dtCol3Gc">loc</div>
      <div class="col-md-6 dtCol3Gc">date</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end dTRow -->
```

### Update(as per OP's request)

Here's updated [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/0rvdk63x) for text-box alignment issues.

Comment: Thanks Vivek, it works. However, the div containing the input box is placing it as per normal flow static position. I am trying to move it in the bottom right corner using: Position: Relative; top:25px ; right: 0; . It pushed down ok but doesn't move sideways.

Comment: @aJ-47 I have updated my answer, please have a look.